# Discovering a disk's physical location

Tags: linux, mount

How can I get Ubuntu Linux to tell me where a mounted filesystem physically lives?

I have inherited an Ubuntu 14.01 VM within a corporate network.  The VM has a shortcut set up which mounts an ext4 partition at /media/parallels/build.  When mounted, mount reveals this about the volume:

```
/dev/sda2 on /media/parallels/build type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
```

The volume is almost certainly a network resource, not part of my machine.  How should I go about getting Linux to reveal more detail about the physical location of the volume - maybe an IP address?

Comment: as mention in the answer `/dev/sda2` is not network based. The VM disk might come from a network mount, but this would come from your hypervisor not from the VM itself.

Comment: I would advise that if you inherited a infra-structure that is not properly documented, you would have to do a discovery/documentation phase of all of it, or if you have to ask here, you would better pay a qualified person to do it ASAP.

Answer (score 6):

`/dev/sdX` drives are SCSI disks (SATA, USB, SD, etc.; [Linux Kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.13/driver-api/scsi.html#sd-scsi-disk)), meaning that they are physically attached to the machine.

Are there any other partitions on `/dev/sda`? Most commonly, `sda` is used for the root drive. See the `lsblk`, `lshw`, and `lsscsi` commands; you may have to install the latter two.

However, since this is a virtual machine, the device *could* be from anywhere, and would be configured through the hypervisor (e.g. VMware, Hyper-V, QEMU/KVM, etc.), you'd have to check its configuration also.

Comment: Welcome and congrats for the nicely written answer. +1

Comment: Not all SCSI devices are physically connected.  iSCSI connected devices are network resources, but will still show up as `/dev/sdX` devices (I think FCoE devices do too, but I'm not sure about that).  Strictly speaking, USB devices may not be physically connected either, as USB can be indirected over the network.